# How to check all filtered records in Activeadmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I've filtered some user's records by criteria. Now I want to send an email for all of them, not only for users that are on first page. How to check all filtered users? 
Something like:

```
collection_action :check_filtered do |items|
    items = collection
    items.check_filtered
end
```

**Update**
After a lot of reading I can be more clear, I hope.

How can I access filtered collection?

```
action_item(:index) do                                                         
  link_to('notify filtered', notify_filtered_admin_users_path(params['q']))  
end
```

What should be in collection action to send mails to all filtered users?

Comment: what do you mean to check ?

Comment: To make checkboxes checked for all filtered records and then to pass ids to batch action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. [Here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2375#issuecomment-159307143)
This line should be edited:

```
instance_exec(resource_class.ransack(params[:q]).pluck(:id), options, &block)
```

to:

```
instance_exec(resource_class.ransack(params[:q]).result.pluck(:id), options, &block)
```

**UPDATE**
Here is extended variant for using with scopes:

```
module ActiveAdmin
    class DSL
      def filtered_batch_action(title, options, &block)
        self.batch_action title, options do |ids, options|
          if params[:collection_selection_toggle_all] != "on"
            instance_exec(ids, options, &block)
          else
            # pluck is ActiveRecord specific, probably needs abstracting
            if params[:q].nil?
              if params[:scope].nil?
                instance_exec(resource_class.pluck(:id), options, &block)
              else
                instance_exec(resource_class.send(params[:scope]).pluck(:id), options, &block)
              end
            else
              instance_exec(resource_class.ransack(params[:q]).result.send(params[:scope]).pluck(:id), options, &block)
            end
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```